# iterrows() is taking hours to run, how can I speed it up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

Below is sample data - 
[image: Sample Data]

Current solution -

```
for idx, row in data.iterrows():

    rp = row['right_player_test']
    lp = row['left_player_test']
    p = row['Player']

    if rp in p:
        data.loc[idx, 'side'] = 'right'

    elif lp in p:
        data.loc[idx, 'side'] = 'left'

    else:
        print('bad -', lp, rp, p)
```

right_player_test is the right player in the 'Matchup_info' field
left_plater_test is the left player in the 'Matchup_info' field
There is more stats in the 'data' DataFrame and they are for whoever is in the 'Player' field

The goal is to determine if the 'Player' is on the left or right side of 'Matchup_info' and assign the result to the 'side' columns so I can get the correct values from the 'Score' field. The number on the left of the '-' in score belongs to the left player and vice versa.

For example, in the first record, `Tihomir Grozdanov` would have a total score of 12 (6+6) and `Vatutin` would end up with a total of 5 (4+1)

The problem is I am doing this for about 250K+ rows(with the possibly of even more) and it is taking hours to finish up. Is there a quicker way to accomplish this?

I can't think of how to use `apply()` here because I need to use 3 columns to calculate the `side` field. The only other solution I can think of right now is trying to use the multiprocessing package but I wanted to see if there was any other pandas alternatives before jumping to that.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest commenting out the statements that write into `data`; that way you'll find out whether reading/iterating is the bottleneck, or if writing is.

Comment: I’m no expert in `pandas` but do you need the `iterrows` here?  Column operations is done on each row.

Comment: How do you know that this loop is taking hours?  Obviously you have more code you haven't shown us that reads in the data and possibly does other things; how do you know the delay isn't in that code?

Comment: I don't know if the native `map` function might be more efficient than the loop. You could generate boolean arrays and use them to index, for example with: `list(map(lambda row: row[1]['right_player_test] in row[1]['player']))`

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample data and results? That would help us solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `numpy` `select`, with `zip`

```
s1=np.array([x in y for x , y in zip(df['right_player_test'],df['Player'])])
s2=np.array([x in y for x , y in zip(df['left_player_test'],df['Player'])])    
np.select([s1,s2,np.logical_and(~s1,~s2)],['right','left','bad'])
```